# How to parse json containing subscript in key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

`{"filter[cname]":"america"}`

How to parse via JSON.parse it returns error.

Comment: is that valid json notation? - try wrapping your key in quotes, like `{
 "filter[cname]": "america"
}`

Comment: updated now please ,DO you know how to parse it ?

Comment: `JSON.parse('{"filter[cname]":"america"}')` doesn't throw an error; it parses just fine. What is it you're struggling with, exactly? What is the exact error you're receiving?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if you are having parsing issues, you can always run your JSON through a [JSON linter](http://jsonlint.com/).

Your updated JSON is valid, but, are you sure you want "filter[cname]" to be a key in your JSON structure?

Perhaps you want something more similar to:

```
var jsonString = '{"am":"america","br":"brazil"}';
var filterMap = JSON.parse(jsonString);

alert(filterMap['am']);
alert(filterMap['br']);
```

JSBin: https://jsbin.com/cehesajete/edit?html,js,output

Comment: try this in your browser console: i am getting this in application i need to parse it 
a= {
"employees[filter]":"asad"
}

Comment: now try to parse a via JSON.parse(a);  crash will be displayed... any solution

Comment: it was able to convert when provided in string literal as you did. but when giving variable to JSON.parse parse error appear so i strigify my json then convert as you did ans work.
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
 Thank you :)